# Subscript out of range (error 9) --- running debugger and going through code everything is fine

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, have this code which uses Vlookups and a match to find past order dates of a particular product. The sub fills text boxes in a userform with N/A if there are no past orders found in the sheet. Otherwise, finds the latest order and fills the information in the userform.

The program stops when this sub routine is called. Getting 'subscript out of range' (error 9), I run the debugger and go through the code and everything works the way it is supposed to. In both the N/A case and the case where there is past order info.

```
Sub PastOrderInfo()

Dim wks As Worksheet

Dim Date_Ordered As Variant
Dim PreviousDate As Variant
Dim Qty_Ordered As String
Dim Total_Cost As String
Dim Rng, RngCol As String

Dim Last_Row As Long

Dim i, NewRow As Integer

Set wks = Worksheets("Order Data")

With wks

    Last_Row = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

    Rng = "A2:D" & Last_Row
    RngCol = "A2:A" & Last_Row

    For i = 2 To Last_Row

        If i = 2 Then


            On Error Resume Next
            PreviousDate = Application.VLookup(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(Rng), 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If IsError(PreviousDate) Then

                Me.TextBox4.Value = "N/A"
                Me.TextBox5.Value = "N/A"
                Me.TextBox6.Value = "N/A"

                Exit Sub

            End If

            NewRow = Application.Match(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(RngCol), 0) + 2
            Rng = "A" & NewRow & ":D" & Last_Row
            RngCol = "A" & NewRow & ":A" & Last_Row

        ElseIf i > 2 Then

            On Error Resume Next
            Date_Ordered = Application.VLookup(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(Rng), 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If IsError(Date_Ordered) Then

                NewRow = NewRow - 1
                Rng = "A" & NewRow & ":D" & Last_Row

                Me.TextBox4.Value = CDate(PreviousDate)
                Me.TextBox5.Value = Application.VLookup(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(Rng), 3, False)
                Me.TextBox6.Value = Application.VLookup(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(Rng), 4, False)

                Exit Sub
            End If

            NewRow = Application.Match(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(RngCol), 0) + NewRow
            Rng = "A" & NewRow & ":D" & Last_Row
            RngCol = "A" & NewRow & ":A" & Last_Row

            If Date_Ordered > PreviousDate Then PreviousDate = Date_Ordered

        End If
    Next i

    Me.TextBox4.Value = CDate(PreviousDate)
    Me.TextBox5.Value = Application.VLookup(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(Rng), 3, False)
    Me.TextBox6.Value = Application.VLookup(CStr(ProdNum), .Range(Rng), 4, False)

End With

End Sub
```

Here is the line which is the section of code which opens the userform, when I click to debug it highlights the ProDescription.Show line below the if .Range(cellselect)...:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i, r, c As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim cellselect As String


Set wks = Workbooks("Data Direct Orders2.xlsx").Worksheets("Direct Items")

With wks
    If ProdNumberCmbBox.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Unload Me

        ErrorMsg.Show
        End

    Else
        For r = 2 To 84
            cellselect = "A" & r
            If .Range(cellselect).Text = ProdNum Then
                ProDescription.Show


                Unload Me
                End
            End If
        Next r

        If c = 0 Then
            Unload Me

            ErrorMsg.Show
            End
        End If

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Here is the sub routine where the userform is initialized:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

TextBox8.Value = ProdNum

Call PastOrderInfo

End Sub
```

Comment: Error comes even though the vlookup values exist and are found.

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: It is a line in a previous sub which calls this sub

Comment: well we would need to see more...

Comment: It errors on a line that is "userform_name".show, in the sub routine where the userform is initialized i have a line that is "call PastOrderInfo" if I comment out the call there is no error.

Comment: Why show this sub if the error is on a line somewhere else?

Comment: Are we supposed to be psychic then?!

Comment: You don't need `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0` wrapped around your call to vlookup, as long as you're testing the return value for an error

Comment: I edited the post and added the other lines.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.
The line:

```
Set wks = Worksheets("Order Data")
```

in

```
Sub PastOrderInfo()
```

Was the problem. Needed to specify the workbook, so after adding:

```
Set wks = Workbooks("VBA - Final Project.xlsm").Worksheets("Order Data")
```

It worked!